# displaying [object object ] instead of data in the variable: ionic

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic3

This is my code

```
this.facebook.login(['email', 'public_profile']).then((response: FacebookLoginResponse) => {
      this.facebook.api('me?fields=id,name,email,first_name,picture.width(720).height(720).as(picture_large)', [])
      .then((profile: any) => {
        let userData = {
          email: profile['email'],
          first_name: profile['first_name'],
          picture: profile['picture_large']['data']['url'],
          username: profile['name'],
          id: profile['id']
        }
        alert(userData);
```

In the emulators alert box, it's showing output as

> [object object]

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: use console.log() because you userData is a object

Answer (score 5):

As your `userData` might be an JSON parsed object, it shows `[object object]`.

Try using `alert(JSON.stringify(userData))` and I guess it should solve your problem.

Also if you just want to verify the object data then you can use simply use
 `console.log(userData)`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use JSON.stringify when you are displaying on alert,

```
 alert(JSON.stringify(userData));
```

Comment: I want to assign the values to the `userData`. after converting into the string how can I read specific values like id,first_name,email etc & assign it to the `userData` variable.

Answer (score 0):

use "console.log(userData);" instead of "alert(userData);"

- alert() is blocking & cannot be easily suppressed in a non-debug environment
- console typically formats your objects nicely and allows to traverse them